# How to name a ContentPage in C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In XAML you name a `ContentPage` like below:

```
<ContentPage ........
             x:Name="ThisPage">
</ContentPage>
```

How do I do this in C#? I can't seem to find any reference about it.

Comment: The name of the `ContentPage` (in this context) is the name of the field it is stored in. In your example `private ContentPage ThisPage;` would be the equivalent C#.

Comment: Why you need to set `x:Name` for a Page ?

Comment: In code behind you could get the current `ContentPage` by invoke `this` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the context how you are consuming it, and what you are using it for, let say you have a `ContentPage`

**YourPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage x:Class="YourNameSpace.YourPage"
....
```

**YourPage.xaml.cs**

```
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public partial class YourPage : ContentPage
    {
        public YourPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example depending on how you consume it (instantiate it):

#### From xaml

**App.xaml**

```
...
    <Application.MainPage>
        <YourNameSpace:YourPage x:Name="ThisPage"/>
    </Application.MainPage>
```

#### Note

What this portion really generate as code can be found in your **obj/** folder with the extension `*.xaml.g.cs` the 'g' stands for "generated":

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        private global::YourNameSpace.YourPage ThisPage;
    }

 private void InitializeComponent() {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(App));
            ThisPage= global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::YourNameSpace.YourPage>(this, "ThisPage");
        }
```

#### From Code

In most usage cases weather in xaml or code the goal is just to have a reference of the page access it after instantiation.

**App.xaml.cs**

As a variable:

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var ThisPage = new YourPage();
            MainPage = ThisPage;
           //ThisPage.DoSomething
        }
    }
```

Or as a class field:

**App.xaml.cs**

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        YourPage ThisPage = new ThisPage();
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = ThisPage;

           //ThisPage.DoSomething
        }

        void Method()
        {
             ...
             //ThisPage.DoSomething
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you name it like you name any C# object

```
var ThisPage = new ContentPage();
```

`ThisPage` is a reference to your element